# Supremum or upper bound of bivariate function involving logarithms and combinatorial coefficients or the gamma function over a region of the integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, gamma-function, upper-bounds

This is a repost from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744769/supremum-or-upper-bound-of-bivariate-function-involving-logarithms-and-combinato) because I got no answers there.

I have been trying to find the supremum of this bivariate function over a specific region. However, the expressions that I get are horrible. I tried Mathematica, but it did not provide a good answer as it gives you something that is clearly not the supremum, as it is smaller than some values I experimented. I hope someone here can help me. I am searching for an upper bound for the function $$\frac{\log\left(\frac{\binom{n}{d}}{2^{d}4}\right)}{d\log(\frac{n}{d})}$$ over the region $\{(n,d)\in\mathbb{N}\mid n>d>0\}.$ I do not need specifically the supremum (although, of course, that would be the best), any (constant) upper bound would also be helpful.

I tried feeding Mathematica with a real extension of this function developing the binomial coefficient using Euler's $\Gamma$ function, which is smooth over the region I am interested in, but Mathematica fails to provide a working upper bound: it gives something that I know it is not an upper bound because I know points in the region having higher value.

Could you help me bounding this function over the region of the integers provided? Does it in fact diverge? If so, how can I see that it diverges?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "good upper bound" and, in particular, by "Mathematica fails to provide a good upper bound"? Also, to make sure: is your $2^d 4$ the same as $2^{d+2}$?

Comment: I need an absolute bound (a constant, whichever constant you can give me would be good) for that function in the mentioned region in case it exists. And if such a bound is not existing, then I would like to know a path in the region that diverges. I tried in Mathematica but it gives me something as an upper bound that I know for sure it is not because I know points in the region with higher value. So Mathematica fails in fact to provide a bound, I will edit to make this more clear. For the last part, yes, they are the same, I only wrote it thus because of the problem the function comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\ln\frac{\binom{n}{d}}{2^{d}4}}{d\ln\frac{n}{d}}
    \le r(n,d):=\frac{\ln\frac{\binom{n}{d}}{2^{d}}}{d\ln\frac{n}{d}};
\end{equation*}
here and in what follows, $n$ and $d$ are integers such that $1\le d\le n-1$, as in the OP. So, it is enough to bound $r(n,d)$ from above by a universal constant.

[We have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)
\begin{equation*}
    \binom{n}{d}\le\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi d(n-d)}}\,2^{nH((d/n))},
\end{equation*}
where $H(p):=-p\log_2 p-(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$.
So, letting
\begin{equation*}
    u:=\frac nd,
\end{equation*}
we get
\begin{equation*}
    d\ge\max(1,\tfrac1{u-1}) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    r(n,d)\le r_1(d,u)+1+r_3(u), \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    r_1(d,u):=\frac{\ln\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi d(n-d)}}}{d\ln\frac{n}{d}}
    =\frac12\frac{\ln\frac u{u-1}-\ln d}{d\ln u}   
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    r_3(u):=\frac{g(u)-\ln2}{\ln u},\quad g(u):=(u-1)\ln\frac u{u-1}. 
\end{equation*}
Given \eqref{1}, we have the elementary inequalities $r_1(d,u)\le1/2$ and $r_3(u)\le1/2$; see details below.

So, by \eqref{2}, $r(n,d)\le2$. $\quad\Box$

**Details on the inequality $r_1(d,u)\le1/2$:** Note that $r_1(d,u)$ is decreasing in $d$ such that $r_1(d,u)>0$. So, by \eqref{1}, (i) $r_1(d,u)\le r_1(1,u)=\frac12\frac{\ln u-\ln(u-1)}{\ln u}\le\frac12$ if $u-1\ge1$ and (ii) $r_1(d,u)\le r_1(\tfrac1{u-1},u)=\frac12\,(u-1)\le\frac12$ if $u-1\le1$.

**Details on the inequality $r_3(u)\le1/2$:** Note that $g''(u)=\frac1{u^2(1-u)}<0$ (for $u>1$), so that $g$ is strictly concave. Also, $g(u)\to1$ as $u\to\infty$. So, $g$ is increasing and $g<1$ . Also, $g(2)=\ln2$ and hence for $u\in(1,2]$ we have $g(u)\le\ln2$, so that $r_3(u)\le0\le1/2$. On the other hand, for $u\ge2$ we have $r_3(u)\le\frac{1-\ln2}{\ln u}\le\frac{1-\ln2}{\ln2}=0.44\ldots<1/2$.